# Shell did output but can not pipe output data

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdout

Command `/usr/sbin/postlog hello` shows output in the terminal. I piped the results to `cat -n` and wanted to add line number, but it did not work at all, even if I pipe both stdout and stderr. I don't know why this may happen.

```
root 18:03:27# /usr/sbin/postlog hello
postfix/postlog: hello

root 18:03:38# /usr/sbin/postlog hello | cat -n
postfix/postlog: hello

root 18:03:49# /usr/sbin/postlog hello |& cat -n

root 18:03:56# /usr/sbin/postlog hello 2>&1 | cat -n
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem and played around a bit. According to the man-page, the output is sent to the postlog-demon, and also to stderr, but the latter only **if stderr is connected to a terminal**. This seems to be weird design decision: If you redirect stderr to a pipe or file, postlog does not write to stderr, and if you don't redirect it, you see the output, but can't catch it. I don't understand, why it has been designed in that way, but suggest that you write a simple cover script, which echos its argument to stdout **and** feeds it to the logging demon, i.e. something like

*script mypostlog*

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/postlog "$@" 2>/dev/null
echo "$@"
```

You can then use this script as

```
mypostlog|cat -n
```

**UPDATE**

As Ed Morton pointed out, this would also suppress `postlog` error messages. If you don't want this to happen, you could do a

```
#!/bin/bash
errfile=/tmp/mypostlog.err.$$
/usr/sbin/postlog "$@" 2>$errfile
printf "%s " "$@"
cat $errfile >&2
rm $errfile
```

The error file would contain only the errors, but no logging.

The solution is still not perfect, in that postlog options are also shown in the `echo`. That is, if you do a

```
mypostlog -p warn MY WARNING
```

would not only display *MY WARNING* in the log, but also write to stdout *-p warn MY WARNING*, instead of a plain *MY WARNING*. If you don't want this to happen, you must basically parse the options as well.

I have also replaced the `echo` of my original proposal `printf` to catch the case when the logging text is something which would be a valid option for `echo` (for instance `-e`).

---

Suggestion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
errfile=$(mktemp) || { printf '%s failed to create temp file.\n' "$0" >&2; exit; }
trap 'rm -f "$errfile"; exit' 0
/usr/sbin/postlog "$@" 2>"$errfile" &&
printf '%s\n' "$*" ||
cat "$errfile" >&2
```

Comment: The obvious caveat there is that if `postlog` encounters an error you'll never know about it given `2>/dev/null`. You could add a test on `$?` before the `echo` I suppose to at least get a warning it did fail in some way. I agree it's an odd design choice from the providers.

Comment: @EdMorton : I just tried it. In this case, the safe solution would be `postlog 2>errorfile.txt`. In this case, errorfile.txt would contain only the error messages. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I added a suggested alternative to the end of your answer that'll be a bit more robust. Feel free to either adopt it or delete it.

Comment: It is indeed. Now we start thinking in this way, how to add a _EXIT_ trap, so that we catch the case that the script is killed before it reaches the final `rm`....?